# Can a javascript check for jQuery and load it if not already present?

Tags: jquery

I'm just looking for a simple javascript that can check to see if the jQuery library is already loaded and if not, loads it.

Thanks in advance if you have a solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is not loaded => load it:
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: This will throw an error on the first line itself if there is no jQuery defined on the page. You should check for typeof instead.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli, correct. Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli, in the comments section :-)

Comment: +1 Thanks Darin. Any thoughts on the pros/cons of loading locally vs from google server?

Comment: Oops. spoke too soon. Unless I explicitly load jQuery with php, I can't get my jQuery slider to work with the code above. I'll troubleshoot it. Might be a document ready issue.

Comment: OK, I see no reason why your code should **not** work. I've probably got a loading/ready issue and that's another question. Thanks Darin!

Answer (score 1):

Load script from Javascript by adding a `<script>` tag:

```
var fileref=document.createElement('script')
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(typeof($) == 'undefined' || typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined'){//JQuery do not exist
    //Load the Jquery from your site or any CDN
}
```