# Trouble with loading jQuery only if not present

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I'm using code [from a blog](http://samespirit.net/ricky/2010/06/21/only-load-jquery-if-not-already-present/), which is very similar to the code in the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708716/can-a-javascript-check-for-jquery-and-load-it-if-not-already-present).

My problem is that the *code places the jQuery include just fine*, but for some reason, scripts after it are not recognizing that jQuery is loaded. What am I doing wrong?

[I've placed the code in a jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JfWeG/)

```
if (!window.loadjQueryOnce)
{
    function loadjQueryOnce(jQueryVersion)
    {
        jQueryVersion = typeof(jQueryVersion) != 'undefined' ? jQueryVersion : "1.7.2";

        if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
            var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
            script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
            script_tag.setAttribute("src",
              "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/" + jQueryVersion + "/jquery.min.js")
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script_tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What application are you doing this in that you need to check for jQuery before loading it?

Comment: It's for everyday use on my pages. Some custom scripts that are included on some pages require jQuery, and having them have this in their code was supposed to make it so if I or another programmer forget to include jQuery, the included script can still run. Looks like it's easier to just remember to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not waiting for the script to be executed before the call in the HTML. [See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/yHfq4/), which uses the code from the blog you mentioned. You need to put the code that relies on jQuery in the `main` function.

Comment: So what would you suggest for including other scripts based on jQuery, such as jQuery-ui, after running my loadjQueryOnce function?

Comment: Use the `main` function to call a similar function to `loadjQueryOnce`, which generates the script tag for jQuery-UI. You'd then need another function like `main` to run once the jQuery-UI script is loaded and executed, which contains anything that depends on jQuery-UI.

Comment: Since I was doing this just to make life easier, I'll just be scrapping this; turns out its easier just to do it the normal way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you move the `loadjQueryOnce('1.7.2')` line to above where you check for jQuery, jQuery is loaded properly.  http://jsfiddle.net/JfWeG/2/  So, I'm not sure where you are doing the checks, but the code does work.

If you want to make sure jQuery is loaded before loading JS files that are dependent on it, then either change your function to load those after loading jQuery, or perform a check on jQuery before every script that uses it.

```
// Load jQueryUI
if (!jQuery) loadjQueryOnce();
loadjQueryUI();

if (!jQuery) loadjQueryOnce();
loadjQueryDepedentScript();
```

It's clunky, but it works.  If you gave us a better idea of why you are doing this, we might be able to help you with a better solution.

Your best bet would be to just create a template where jQuery is the first thing loaded in the head:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        ...
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a timing issue. If you create a small delay before checking, it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {
    if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
        alert('Not recognizing jQuery');
    }
}, 100);​
</script>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JfWeG/3/)**.

Comment: How can I include other scripts like jQuery-ui after my `loadjQueryOnce()` function if I have to run this delay?

Comment: And even with the 100 timeout in your example, it's still telling me it's not recognizing it, although 1000 does the trick.

Comment: Well the 100 millisecond delay was just for a test, you can obviously adjust that. Polling to see if jQuery was loaded could be one way to then load UI, although that seems kludgy.

Comment: Yea the whole point of this was to make it quick and easy to only check and load jQuery once. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Aside from just including it without checking, not that I'm aware of. Is this for a plugin of some sort?

Comment: It's for everyday use on my pages. Some custom scripts that are included on some pages require jQuery, and having them have this in their code was supposed to make it so if I or another programmer forget to include jQuery, the included script can still run. Looks like it's easier to just remember to include it, hah.

Comment: @j08691 My answer (and the original blog post's code) uses the `onload` event (and `readyState` for IE), which is what should be used instead of a hard-coded delay.