# check whether jquery is already defined or not

Tags: jquery

Hi i am trying to create a plugin for my client, i will just add the following code in their html.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var clientID = "123";

    (function() {
        var test = document.createElement('script'); test.type = 'text/javascript'; test.async = true;
        test.src = 'myjavascript.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(test, s);
    })();
    </script>

    <div id="addimage"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And in myjavascript.js file i will call the jquery library.

```
if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://mysite.com/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}


if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://mysite.com/js/fancybox.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

// my rest code goes here
```

So i would like to check whether the client html already has to call for jquery-1.7.1.min.js if not, then only include the 1.7.1.min.js file in myquery.js

How to check whether its already included or not. Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a javascript check for jQuery and load it if not already present?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708716/can-a-javascript-check-for-jquery-and-load-it-if-not-already-present)

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if jquery has been loaded, then load it if false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828237/check-if-jquery-has-been-loaded-then-load-it-if-false)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if jquery has been loaded, then load it if false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828237/check-if-jquery-has-been-loaded-then-load-it-if-false)

Answer (score 10):

Usually you use `!!variable` to see if a variable is set or not. This way is used in many, many famous frameworks so I tend to use it as well.

```
if(!!window.jQuery) {
    // jQuery is loaded
} else {
    // load jQuery first
}
```

Looking at your question though, your method should work too! Using `typeof variable === 'undefined'` is a very valid approach as well.

---

Edit: Apparently this isn't enough information so I'll just rewrite your code

```
if(!window.jQuery) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://mysite.com/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: @user100311 I have changed my code a little bit. If jQuery is **not** defined you want to define it. That means you have to put the code you use to load jQuery in the `else` block. Also, you can remove the if-statement you currently use to check if jQuery is defined or not.

Comment: @user100311 I have edited the code, you should be able to copy-paste the code now...

Answer (score 2):

in Addition to `Tim S.` answer you can use $.jquery to get the version

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
if(!! jQuery && jQuery('body').jquery == '1.7.1'){

    // jquery 1.7.1 included so only put your script
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://mysite.com/js/myotherscripts';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    head.appendChild(script);


} else {

    // Include jquery first 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://mysite.com/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    head.appendChild(script);

    // Then include your scripts
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://mysite.com/js/myotherscripts';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    head.appendChild(script);

}
```

Comment: @tim i added like this    if(!! jQuery && jQuery('body').jquery == '1.7.1'){

if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://..../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

} and it dosnt work.

Comment: @user100311 Look at the comments and my edit at my answer... You can't expect everyone to start discussing in the comments section at a single answer - you have to look around. You can also look at your profile (there's a link in the top bar) where you can easily see new responses marked in blue.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeof jQuery != "undefined") {
   $('.input-number').inputmask('+7 (999) 999-9999');
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.