# Magento extension development jquery

Tags: jquery, magento

I am currently developing my first extension which I intend on selling on magento connect.

I am going to require jquery.

If I include jquery in my module it might potentially overwrite a version the user already has installed. If I don't include it the user would have to install it themselves which is undesirable. If I namespace or specify jquery's version in the filename it might end up conflicting with another version of jquery they have installed themselves, or that has been installed by another module.

Is there some standard solution to this problem?

Comment: You can check if jQuery is not already included.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708716/can-a-javascript-check-for-jquery-and-load-it-if-not-already-present

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `noConflict()` property. Add your jQuery file in your extension and at the bottom of jQuery file, you just insert

```
jExt=jQuery.noConflict()` //jExt is a custom variable
```

and use variable `jExt` instead of `jQuery` or `$` references (in all of their places) in your files. This will totally avoid conflict issues.